# What is the normal temperature for my computer?

Tags: intel, temperature, motherboard

What is the normal temperature for an Acer Homa GL40 chipset?
Laptop technical specifications:

- Acer Extensa 5230e
- Motherboard: Intel GL40
- CPU: Intel mobile core 2 solo @ 2.20 GHz

During idle processing, the motherboard temperature is about 45 degrees centigrade and in load is about 55 degree centigrade

*Is it too high? And what is the normal temperature for this motherboard?*

Answer (score 2):

### Stop worrying! ;-)

My Fujitsu Siemens is running at 58°C at low load, 75°C at medium load and 85°C at high load. the NVidia CPU is running at 45°C when *disabled* and 85°C-93°C while gaming.

To get the maximum temperature (T°) for your own system just:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sensors
```

and you should get something like:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.8°C  (crit = +110.8°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +54.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:       +51.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

where you should keep the T° 5°C below the critical T° to have a very long system life...